# Conditionally hide the node comments via preprocess function

Tags: 8, nodes, comments

I have learned how to hide the display of the author and the creation date of a node, depending on the content of a taxonomy field.
Is it going to hide the comment on the same way?

```
function mytheme_preprocess_node(&$variables) {

  // check if this is the right content type where the field exists
  if ($variables['node']->getType() != 'article') {
    return;
  }

  // taxonomy field
  $field = $variables['node']->field_where_to_publish;

  if (!$field->isEmpty() && $field->entity->label() == 'public') {

    // How to hide the comment for this entity label?
  }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$variables['content']['comment']['#access'] = FALSE;
```

That should work, assuming you use the default comment field named "comment", otherwise whatever you named it. Comments are just a field, nothing special about them.

You can also check it directly in twig and not print it there.

Comment: thanks a lot, this works. 
>You can also check it directly in twig and not print it there.
I have no experience with twig, but I will remember that.

Comment: I 've to hide the link "write new comment", in german "Neuen Kommentar schreiben" also.

Comment: Hiding just that link in case you have multiple isn't that easy, but hiding all the links is, that's links within content.

Comment: Wow, this works with everything that's inside `$variables['content']`, all normal fields as well.